# French Word Acronyms

Tags: abréviations

In french speaking areas it's not uncommon to come across word acronyms, like:

- **RDC**: *rez-de-chaussée*
- **SVP**:  *s'il vous plaît*

English speakers also frequently use **RSVP** (*répondez s'il vous plaît*).

What other common word acronyms are there?